Xrange highchart shows wrong tooltip if startTime the same
xrange highchart shows wrong tooltip if the startTime is the same for series data. I am using Highcharts JS v7.0.1. Has anyone had the same problem?
[
    {
        "color": "#00AB9A",
        "x": 1725479999999,
        "x2": 1733256000000,
        "y": 0
    },
    {
        "color": "#00AB9A",
        "x": 1725479999999,
        "x2": 1733342400000,
        "y": 1
    }
]


Hi @Vahe Akhsakhalyan, Could you describe more precisely what you mean by the wrong tooltip? Please refer to this live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/taw1pnhj/
